# How to serve static content from Azure Mobile Service C# backend

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm running a mobile services instance (**C# backend**) and besides all the other functionality, I also need to host a few html pages and their respective css files.

Here is what I tried:

1. If I browse to `http://<service-url>/myfile.html` I get an 404 error. So I
   created a `myfile.html` file and stuck it in the project root folder. Now, instead of 404, I get a blank page.
2. I tried going through the `ContentController` by putting the html file in `<project root>\api\Content\Views\myfile.html`. When I browse to `http://<service-url>/api/Content/Views/myfile.html` I get a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

**Update Dec, 2015**
Now that Microsoft published App Services you should probably use that - create a mobile app and a web app and you're done.
Don't try to hack around with Mobile Services.
It always felt to me that Mobile Services were a half baked solution. It is more a competitor to Parse.com and similar BaaS and was missing a lot of the stuff you'd expect from an Azure service.

**Update**
The solution below does not work but it does teach you a lot about how the mobile service is built. The reason the solution does not work is that Azure refuses to upload the static files to the mobile service instance.

You start by understanding what is Owin and that mobile services are using one. [This post](http://chris.59north.com/post/2014/05/20/Understanding-OWIN-%E2%80%93-more-on-the-IAppBuilder-abstraction-and-middleware-creation.aspx) helped me a lot.

Then you look in [this link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/10/building-a-simple-file-server-with-owin-and-katana.aspx) which explains how to build a file server using katana.

Here are short instructions:

Install nuget package `Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles`.

Plug into the `OwinAppBuilder` and instruct it to use Katana's file server just before you run the original (put this in `WebApiConfig.cs`):

```
var originalAppBuilder = StartupOwinAppBuilder.OwinAppBuilder;
StartupOwinAppBuilder.Initialize(builder =>
{
    builder.UseFileServer("/static");
    originalAppBuilder(builder);
}
```

Create a `static` folder in your project root, put some files there and browse to `<your service url>/static/somefile.html`.